# Unity 2d diffuse sprites not rendering on mobile

Tags: unity, 2d

EDIT:  Just an update, did change from sprite/diffuse to Diffuse and zordering of my level using t2dtk map stuff was backwards. Like the camera flipped around so i had to shuffle things around on the Z axis.  Also things that were rendering in 2d with their y rotated 180 degrees no longer were so I had to change how the other engine I was using (Corgi engine) was moving projectiles.

This all worked then in the editor.  When I pushed to the system, still nothing renders unless the rendering path is legacy vertex lit.  And then it will render but dark like my directional light and point lights are meaningless.  Apparently I am not cool enough to mess with Shaders/Unity 5 and mobile.

It seems like Mobile is having an issue rendering my diffuse sprites.  I just made some of the sprites in my game diffuse so point lights would give them a nice lit up effect.  This works great on PC but when I push the game to my mobile phone (a Galaxy Note 3) nothing that has that diffuse material renders at all.  I am assuming it is just setting but I cannot figure out for the life me how to get this to work.  I tried to muck with settings (rendering paths etc) nothing seemed to help.  Of note:  The stuff renders fine in Unity editor when the mobile target is selected even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put my money on shader problems here.  Typically one "shader" script contains multiple options of CG programs, generally the ones with the higher hardware / software requirements go at the top of the script, and older / slower devices fallback to the best of the lesser shaders they can support.  I'd take a peek at the "Diffuse" Shader Script you are using to see what exactly the fallbacks are doing.  (In version 5.0 Unity actually classified nearly all of the previous shaders as "Legacy" and reorganized the remaining to better differentiate the new PBR stuff.)

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Fallback.html

## tldr; All of the back story aside...

You should be able to find less resource intensive shaders specifically designed for mobile under the Material : Shader > Mobile > Diffuse, from the drop down.  Try this one:

[image: Dropdown]

Comment: ty so much for helping me with this.  I cannot test on mobile but I did find that mobile diffuse shader.  it is not a sprite shader and something peculiar happened when I used it.  Before unity  5 came out, I was on 4.x.something and things were great after I think a late version of 4 or 5 came out I had big issues with lights disappearing and what not, turns out z coords were switched smoehow

Comment: Ugh commenting system:  So I had to change the coords of my backgrounds in my tile map, from -0.1 on z to 0.1 on z to get them behind the foreground again, all from this diffuse sprite to diffuse.  I am confused why, also some sprites that now fire left they don't render.  It is a rotation thing but all I changed was the diffuse on my tilemap sprites.  I am so confuses as to what is causing these woes.

Comment: okay I hope you will help (I need to upvote your answer) but I have to say, I am confused what goes on here.   My projectiles can fire in any angle (using the Corgi engine from asset store).  Though to do that it calculates the angle based on facing etc also.  So if I fire right, projectile shows up, if i fireleft its there but not rendered the rotation says 180 on the Y.  I am not sure how any of this diffuse sprite stuff is related and causing this.  I would love insight as to whats going on just to learn and fix it too.

Comment: I bit the bullet and just changed my code to fix the projectiles and had to do some other things with how things were spawned as the zordering seems to change with that diffuse change.